# macos 10.11 install mysql and prompt “dyld: Symbol not found: _SSL_library_ini”

Tags: mysql, macos

my mac os version is 10.11.6;when i install mysql finish;i use "mysql -u root -p" and input password;the console prompt:

Enter password:
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _SSL_library_init
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mysql
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _SSL_library_init
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mysql
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib

Comment: Did you solve this in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem earlier today (except with `wget` after a seemingly trivial macOS point update). You might have to try reinstalling `mysql` or an updated version of it and go from there. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error after having mistakenly installed a newer version of MySQL Shell than was compatible with my version of OSX. Had to uninstall and then install the correct older version from the MySQL archive.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was caused by a version mismatch.  I had downloaded the current version of MySQL but was running a three-year-old version of MacOS.

To resolve it I needed to go to the [MySQL Community Archive](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/) page and install the correct MySQL version for that OS.

Unfortunately, the Community Archive page doesn't seem to have a quick way to filter only by a specific MacOS version. You have to first pick a MySQL version from the `Product Version` dropdown and then select the `OS Version` field to get the MacOS version it supports.

[Screenshot of MySQL Archive page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQfKc.png)